# How to make Sortable lists with some items that can't be dragged with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable

I used this [code](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) to build 7 different lists. The items in it can be dragged around freely between those lists. Now i want to have some items to be fixed in their lists, so they can't be dragged around anymore. How could i do that?

Comment: Its in the docs: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items

Comment: nice, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this one

HTML

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-disabled">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-disabled">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight ui-state-disabled">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight ui-state-disabled">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Java-Script

```
$( function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
       items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
    }).disableSelection();
  } );
```

CSS

```
 #sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
```

you can check this link http://jsfiddle.net/yrmewjok/